# Single sign-on (Windows domain) not working in Edge + IIS + ASP.NET Core 6.0

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, single-sign-on, ms-yarp

I am trying to set up a simple reverse proxy app in ASP.NET Core (using Microsoft's Yarp.ReverseProxy), hosting it in IIS.
It is supposed to provide the user name of the authenticated user via a header (`X-Authenticated-Username`).

My code:

`Server.cs` (a renamed `Program.cs`):

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Security;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Yarp.ReverseProxy.Forwarder;

namespace Foo;

public class Server {

  // in the actual code, these are taken from configuration
  private const string ConnectionTimeout = "45";
  private const string DestinationPrefix = "http://initech.com/stapler/swingline/red";
  private const string HeaderName = "X-Authenticated-Username";
  private const string RequestTimeout = "123";

  public static void Main(string[] args) {
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    {
      var services = builder.Services;
      services.AddHttpForwarder();
      services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddNegotiate();
      // It's unclear whether these actually matter (I think they're for the obsolete "integrated authentication").
      // Out of Process
      services.Configure<IISOptions>(options => {
        options.AuthenticationDisplayName = "Foo Proxy (IIS Out-of-Process)";
        options.AutomaticAuthentication = true;
      });
      // In-Process
      services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options => {
        options.AuthenticationDisplayName = "Foo Proxy (IIS In-Process)";
        options.AutomaticAuthentication = true;
      });
    }
    var app = builder.Build();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    // FIXME: These are sample settings; which ones are truly relevant? And which could/should be made configurable?
    var httpClient = new HttpMessageInvoker(new SocketsHttpHandler {
      UseProxy = false,
      AllowAutoRedirect = false,
      AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.None,
      UseCookies = false,
      ActivityHeadersPropagator = new ReverseProxyPropagator(DistributedContextPropagator.Current),
      ConnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Server.ConnectionTimeout),
    });
    var transformer = new AddAuthenticatedUserHeader(Server.HeaderName);
    var requestConfig = new ForwarderRequestConfig {
      ActivityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Server.RequestTimeout),
    };
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
      endpoints.MapForwarder("/{**catch-all}", Server.DestinationPrefix, requestConfig, transformer, httpClient);
    });
    app.Run();
  }

}
```

(Note: the `IIS*Options` configuration lines make no difference either way; I have left them in just in case.)

`AddAuthenticatedUserHeader.cs`

```cs
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Yarp.ReverseProxy.Forwarder;

namespace Foo;

public sealed class AddAuthenticatedUserHeader : HttpTransformer {

  public string HeaderName { get; }

  public AddAuthenticatedUserHeader(string headerName) {
    this.HeaderName = headerName;
  }

  public override async ValueTask TransformRequestAsync(HttpContext httpContext, HttpRequestMessage proxyRequest,
                                                        string destinationPrefix, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
    await base.TransformRequestAsync(httpContext, proxyRequest, destinationPrefix, cancellationToken);
    var logger = httpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ILogger<AddAuthenticatedUserHeader>>();
    // If a user name is available, add a header for it.
    var userName = httpContext.User.Identity?.Name;
    if (userName is not null) {
      logger.LogInformation("Passing the authenticated user name ({name}) via the '{header}' header.", userName,
                            this.HeaderName);
      proxyRequest.Headers.Add(this.HeaderName, userName);
    }
    else {
      logger.LogInformation("Not setting a '{header}' header because no authenticated user name is available.",
                            this.HeaderName);
    }
  }
}
```

The proxying works fine in and of itself.

The problem is getting it to work so that the user's Windows domain account is used automatically.
A separate site was created in IIS (listening on port 12345 on all names/interfaces); authentication at the IIS level only has Windows Authentication enabled. The simple ASP.NET Core 6.0 app uses the Negotiate authentication extension.

When I connect using "http://localhost:12345", I get:

- using Edge, Chrome and Opera, it works perfectly

  - no login dialog, and header gets set
- using Firefox, it sorta works

  - SSO is enabled in Firefox settings
  - there is a login dialog (indistinguishable from basic auth), but pressing "Sign in" a couple of
    times (without entering anything!) works, and the header gets set

However, when I connect using "http://my.machine.name:12345", I get:

- using Firefox, same as above, so it kinda works
- in Edge, I get a Windows Security dialog; this does already mention my Windows domain name,
  so it's at least clear that you are expected to enter your Windows user/pass
- in Chrome and Opera, I get a normal login dialog (indistinguishable from basic auth). Unlike in
  Firefox, just clicking Sign In without entering anything does nothing. Entering my credentials
  explicitly does work.

So I guess what it boils down to is:

1. How do I get the automatic authentication to work when not connecting via localhost?
2. How do I get Firefox to play nice and not show the login dialog at all? (This is less important; it kinda works as it is, and my immediate use case is likely only for Edge.)

Comment: The behaviors you observed are purely controlled by browser side settings, so not much to discuss on server side. Domain administrators should be more familiar with them than developers and they can use domain policies to control some. Note that Firefox plays very differently and that's well known.

Comment: You can try opening Firefox and typing `about:config` in the address bar.
Accept the warning and search for `network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris`.
Add the server's URL (for example, http://my.machine.name:12345) to the list of trusted URIs.
Set the value of `network.negotiate-auth.allow-non-fqdn` to true. This allows non-FQDN sites to use negotiated authentication. After making these changes, Firefox should automatically authenticate without showing a login dialog.